# In Openlayers How to render multiple bands geotiff tile from WMTS?

Tags: openlayers

I have loaded muiltple bands geotiff using Openlayers with ol.source.WMTS,

And I want to render customized style with some of the bands value.

I kown I can use geotiff.js and canvas or COG Geotiff to realize ,but too slow and browser crash when the tif tiles are more then 500KB. I want to use then WebGLTile or other in Openlayers .I try like this:

```
  const wmtsSource = new WMTS({
  url: 'https://www.test.com/service/wmts?',
  layer: 'test:res_4',
  format: 'application/bandstiff',
  matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857',
  attributions: [
  ],
  tileGrid: tileGrid,
  dimensions: {
    'threshold': 100,
  },
});
const max = 3000;
  function normalize(value) {
    return ['/', value, max];
  }

  const red = normalize(['band', 1]);
  const green = normalize(['band', 2]);
  const blue = normalize(['band', 3]);
  const nir = normalize(['band', 4]);

  const trueColor = {
    color: ['array', red, green, blue, 1],
    gamma: 1.1,
  };

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    projection: projection,
    center: [13092106, 3693413],
    zoom: 10,
  }),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      visible: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
      style : trueColor,
      source: wmtsSource,
    }),
    ]
    
    });
```

[image]

This is the geotiff which can get from above code.It is 6 bands stadard geotiff:
[image]

but I can not set their style.The rendering result is blank.
Who know how can I realize this?

When I add Mike's code,it will not request wmts tile.The page will crash about 4 mimutes later:
[image]

Can you give me some clues,thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with a tile pyramid as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-pyramid.html and use the WMTS source's url function to obtain the url

```
new WebGLTileLayer({
  sources: sourcesFromTileGrid(
    tileGrid,
    ([z, x, y]) =>
      new GeoTIFF({
        sources: [
          {
            url: wmtsSource.getTileUrlFunction()([z, x, y]),
          },
        ],
      })
  ),
});
```

**UPDATE**

I cannot get your tiles to load via a url but they do work when loaded as a blob as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-blob.html, but that is not convenient for a pyramid using `sourcesFromTileGrid`.  Instead I used geotiff.js directly and loaded into data tiles, which does seem very heavy on memory.

```
import {fromBlob} from 'geotiff'

function getData(rasters) {
  const ii = rasters.length;
  const data = new Float32Array(256 * 256 * ii);
  for (let x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
      const px = x + y * 256;
      for (let i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
        data[px * ii + i] = rasters[i][y * 256 + x];
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}

new WebGLTileLayer({
  source: new DataTileSource({
    tileGrid: tileGrid,
    loader: (z, x, y) => 
      fetch(wmtsSource.getTileUrlFunction()([z, x, y]))
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject()
          }
          return response.blob()
        })
        .then((blob) => fromBlob(blob))
        .then((tiff) => tiff.getImage())
        .then((image) => image.readRasters())
        .then((rasters) => getData(rasters)),
  }),
  style: trueColor,
}),
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have added your code into my code.But It doest works. My previous code can get wmts tiff tile normally:new TileLayer({
      visible: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
      style : trueColor,
      source: wmtsSource,
    })  .    But your code cant get the tiff tile normally and there is nothing err in "Console". It did not request tile from server.When I refresh the page ,it crash ,I have to close this page to open another page. Do you know the reason ,thank you .

Comment: If a normal WMTS source can load the tiles they cannot be in GeoTIFF format, and a GeoTIFF source would be unable to read them.  Are they actually png or jpeg with data in the alpha channel?

Comment: They are 6 bands stadard geotiff ,not png or jpeg.I have post the picture above.Is your    code used for COG format ? And It can not be used the wmts geotiff tile ?

Comment: If I google search 'application/bandstiff' the only result is this question, so I think it might be non-standard format.  Is the url you are using public so we can examine what is being served?  Otherwise I don't think anyone can help you

Comment: Yes,you are right.I create this format myself.It is used as a extension of Geoserver which I publish multiple bands geotiff tile service.You can visit this url to get its WMTS url: "http://47.94.232.132:5173/ " . You can download the tile then render by QGIS. WebGL is so efficient but I dont know how to use WebGL to render this kind geotiff wmts tile efficient.Thank you.

Comment: The tiles work when loaded as a blob, but not directly from the url.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes,some days ago I use geotiff.js in Leaflet small tile for example 40KB the browser can render the tiff sytle normally .But when the tiff tiles are bigger for example 400KB,the browser will crash because of heavy memory.So I want to use WebGL in Openlayers ,but now I can not find the ready-made API in Openlayers.Mybe we should develop a new API to realize the need?I dont know.When I use cog geotiff API ,although the tiff tiles are big 400KB it can render its style quickly and smoothly.